# Why gdal does not find gcps coordinates on SENTINEL images?

Tags: python, gdal, gdalwarp, sentinel-1

I use gdalwarp with python to overlay polygons on ENVISAT radar images. Everything goes well for this type of images but when I try with SENTINEL images, gdal does not find the georeferencing. It seems that gdal takes the global coordinates of the pixel at the upper left of the image. When I read the image information with gdalinfo, I realize that ENVISAT images have no gcp while SENTINEL images have. I have this error message when I use gdalwarp with SENTINEL images:

> The transformation is already "north up" or a transformation between pixel/line and georeferenced coordinates cannot be computed for tmp_spill.tif. There is no affine transformation and no GCPs. Specify transformation option SRC_METHOD=NO_GEOTRANSFORM to bypassthis check.

I do not understand why it does not find gcps when they display well with gdalinfo. I use this line for overlay polygon on ENVISAT images : `cmd='gdalwarp --config GDALWARP_IGNORE_BAD_CUTLINE YES -q -dstnodata None -cutline tmp.shp %s %s'%('tmp_seep.tif',classout_seep)`.

Do you know why gdal does not find gcps coordinates ?

Comment: which sentinel product are you downloading? sentinel 2 is provided in different levels of preprocessing.

Comment: I take sentinel images on the esa website. When i use gdalinfo on a sentinel images i have this type of result : `Size is 26178, 16870
Coordinate System is '
GCP Projection =
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
GCP[  0]: Id=1, Info=
          (0,0) -> (11.6038164704897,-8.78663832897941,-1.14552676677704e-05)`

Comment: You mean that for you gdalinfo shows something different than in the examples in https://gdal.org/frmt_sentinel2.html? What is your GDAL version?

Comment: I use sentinel 1A and 1B images. My result look like L1B subdataset at the bottom of your link. I have the 2.2.2 gdal version on python 2.7.14.